# Webpack cannot debug `import ... from ...` variable; How to make webpack keep `import from` variable name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

For ex, my code is

```
import React from "react"

var node = <div></div>
```

when I set breakpoint in chrome devtools in `var node = <div></div>` line, it raise error:

```
VM183:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

[image]

I know the reason is because webpack compile `import React, {createRef} from "react"; to following code

```
var react_1 = __importStar(__webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js"));
```

but I don't know how to prevent it

**how to fix it?**

Comment: I believe you can solve it with some additional compiler flags, such as `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop`.

Comment: @Marty no, I enable `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` in tsconfig and restart webpack-dev-server, this bug still exist, it's not typescript issue, it's webpack issue

Comment: I’m pretty sure you need to do `import * as React from 'react'`

Comment: I get this problem ALL THE TIME.  Like, I probably spend 5% of my time trying to find some workaround for WebPack's bugs.  I don't remember it happening with React, but that's just because it's happened so much with important stuff.  Sometimes, the variable is simply not found from the debugger.  Other times, the software crashes because some member variable that should be an object, mysteriously ends up undefined.  Other code can access the same variable before and after, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

update:
following [webpack plugin](https://gist.github.com/staeke/f197ff144e379aa884f91b95003f4ee1) only support webpack4, but I refer it and make webpack plugin to fix this bug for webpack 5, my code is huge so only give mechanism:

override(with js prototype) webpack get import statement, record source imported var

override webpack apply import var, restore import var to source imported var

update:

I find following issue:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3957

in the end, it give a custom webpack plugin, it should fix

https://gist.github.com/staeke/f197ff144e379aa884f91b95003f4ee1

full code is here:

```
import {App} from "../src/App";

in webpack output become

var App_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! ../src/App */ "./src/App.tsx");

update:
the solution is make webpack plugin to hack webpack compiler(make webpack don't rename import from variable name)
https://gist.github.com/staeke/f197ff144e379aa884f91b95003f4ee1

the full webpack plugin code:

// This is a hack to just simplify variable namings, because they're ugly, for easier debugging
const HarmonyImportDependency = require('webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportDependency');
const HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency = require('webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency');
const HarmonyImportSpecifierDependencyTemplate = HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.Template;
const path = require('path');

const HIDproto = HarmonyImportDependency.prototype;
const HISDTproto = HarmonyImportSpecifierDependencyTemplate.prototype;

const originalGetImportVar = HIDproto.getImportVar;
const originalGetImportStatement = HIDproto.getImportStatement;
const originalGetContent = HISDTproto.getContent;

const DEFAULT_MODULE_VAR_NAME_FN = str => {
  return '__' +  path.basename(str).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9$]+/g, '_');
}

module.exports = class SimplifyNamesPlugin {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  toIdentifier(str, scope) {
    if (!str || typeof str !== 'string') return str;

    let out = (this.options.moduleVarNameFn || DEFAULT_MODULE_VAR_NAME_FN)(str)

    const taken = scope.importVarMapVals || (scope.importVarMapVals = new Set());

    if (taken.has(out)) {
      let extra = '';
      while (taken.has(out + extra)) {
        const num = parseInt(extra.substr(1) || '0') + 1;
        extra = '_' + num;
      }
      out = out + extra;
    }

    taken.add(out);

    return out;
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('HarmonyModulesPlugin', (compilation, {normalModuleFactory}) => {
      normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser
        .for('javascript/auto')
        .tap('HarmonyModulesPlugin', (parser, parserOptions) => {
          parser.hooks.importSpecifier.tap('HarmonyImportDependencyParserPlugin', (statement, source) => {
            const deps = parser.state.module.dependencies;
            deps[deps.length - 1].statement = statement;
          });
        });
    });


    if (HIDproto.getImportVar === originalGetImportVar) {
      const self = this;

      HIDproto.getImportVar = function() {
        let importVarMap = this.parserScope.importVarMap;
        if (!importVarMap) this.parserScope.importVarMap = importVarMap = new Map();
        let importVar = importVarMap.get(this.module);
        if (importVar) return importVar;
        importVar = self.toIdentifier(this.userRequest, this.parserScope);
        importVarMap.set(this.module, importVar);
        return importVar;
      }

      HIDproto.getImportStatement = function() {
        const orig = originalGetImportStatement.apply(this, arguments).replace('/* harmony import */ ', '');
        const specifiers = this.statement &&  this.statement.specifiers;
        if (specifiers) {
          const importSpecifiers = specifiers.filter(s => s.type === 'ImportSpecifier');
          const importVars = importSpecifiers.map(s => {
            if (!s.imported)
              return null
            if (!s.local || s.local.name === s.imported.name)
              return s.imported.name;
            return s.imported.name + ':' + s.local.name
          }).filter(x => !!x)
          const defaultSpecifier = specifiers.find(s => s.type === 'ImportDefaultSpecifier');
          let last = ''
          const vals = [...this.parserScope.importVarMap.values()]
          const moduleName = [...vals][vals.length - 1]
          if (defaultSpecifier) {
            const name = defaultSpecifier.local.name
            importVars.push('default:' + name);
            last = `;if(typeof ${name}==="undefined")${name}=${moduleName}`
          }
          return `${orig.substr(0, orig.length - 1)}let {${importVars.join(',')}} = ${moduleName}${last};\n`;
        }
        return orig;
      };

      HISDTproto.getContent = function() {
        const orig = originalGetContent.apply(this, arguments);
        let out = orig;
        if (orig.startsWith('Object('))
          out = orig.substr(7, orig.length - 8);
        const match = out.match(/^(.+)\["([^\]]+)"]$/);
        if (match) {
          const legalId = match[2].match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9$]*$/);
          if (legalId) {
            out = match[1] + '.' + match[2];
          }
        }
        return out;
      };
    }
  }
};
```

old:

My tmp solution is, when use typescript, use `const varName = require("path/to/lib")`, instead of `import varName from "path/to/lib"`

it will work

but I still wanna find a way to support debug var from `import from`(since most code style is `import from` not `const require`)

Answer (score -1):

Allow me to plug my plugin which i created, to remedy this problem:

https://github.com/trias/debug-import-vars-webpack-plugin

install it with `npm i -D debug-names-webpack-plugin`
and add it to your webpack.config.js

```
const DebugNamesPlugin = require("debug-names-webpack-plugin");

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new DebugNamesPlugin()
  ]
}
```

after recompiling with webpack, it should now be possible to use imported vars in the debugger